# Does Mathematica provide access to data which is not available in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: curated-data

Does Mathematica provide access to data which is not available in Wolfram Alpha?

For example, I asked Wolfram Alpha "US fertility number of children" because I want to know the distribution of women in the US by the number of children they have had. Eg 40% no children, 30% 1 child, 20% 2 children, etc. However, Wolfram Alpha came up with nothing, just the net fertility rate (1.87) which I already knew.

Would it be futile to try to find this data through Mathematica because they use the same source data and queries, or will Mathematica have additional sources, not available in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: They use the same databases for the most part. If you couldn't find what you're looking for in Alpha with a well worded query then it is likely not available in Mathematica as well. I think.

Answer (score 3):

The general answer to the question in the title is no, Alpha has more information than is available in *Mathematica*.  That's because they can include more experimental stuff in alpha, and aren't tied to the general *Mathematica* release cycle.  Things do work there way from Alpha to *Mathematica* (try out `Interpreter["YogaPose"]["Vriksasana"]` in version 11), but it can take time.

It is sometimes a matter of formulating the right query to get the data you want, although I can't seem to find the info you are looking for.  I had a hard time finding it on the web, but [this page](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2015/05/07/appendix-a-additional-tables-4/) seems to be it.  More tables [here](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2015/05/07/childlessness-falls-family-size-grows-among-highly-educated-women/st_2015-05-07_childlessness-12/) as well, but the underlying dataset I couldn't find.